# What type of message will I receive for a event from libSimEventsPlugin.so?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> ```
>     <plugin
> ```

```
>         <filename="libSimEventsPlugin.so"
>         <name="event_plugin">
>         <region>
>         <name>Region1</name>
>         <volume>
>         <min> 0 0 0 </min>
>         <max> 1 1 1 </max> 
>         </volume>
>         </region>
>         <event>
>         <name>region1_event</name>
>         <type>occupied</type>
>         <region>Region1</region>
>         <topic>~/elevator</topic>
>         <msg_data>received message CONGRATS </msg_data>
>         </event> 
>         </plugin>
```

My callback function is like this:

```
void cb(ConstSimEventPtr &msg);
```

I've also tried as in the [following link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=topics_subscribed&ver=6%2B):

```
void cb(ConstWorldStatisticsPtr &_msg)
```

The problem is that when I spawn my model in the specified region, the application crashes with the following message:

```
gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = const gazebo::msgs::WorldStatistics; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = const gazebo::msgs::WorldStatistics*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**My question is: what data type is the msg that I have to receive from the plugin?**

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25799/what-type-of-message-will-i-receive-for-a-event-from-libsimeventsplugin.so?/) by [dragobette](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/31660/dragobette/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

it is a `ConstGzStringPtr` , and the error means that a null pointer was stored in a shared pointer that was dereferenced ***specifically a `boost::shared_ptr<gazebo::msgs::WorldStatistics>`***.

---

Originally posted by [dragobette](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/31660/dragobette/) with karma: 1 on 2020-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0